# Does "race against" mean "sail"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

---

> ***High clouds raced against the sky***

American chapters, The storm, Greta Gorsuch

---

Does "race against" mean "sail" in this context?

Comment: If that's a reference for the quote, please [edit] your question and add it there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here *raced* means moved swiftly. *Against* highlights that the sky is the apparent backdrop that’s visually behind them.